# Unit Test Click event in typescript

Tags: unit-testing, typescript2.0

I need to test the click events of the following code using karma jasmine. The project is of only typescript.

```
   private createLabel() {

    buttonLabel.htmlElement.onclick= () => {
    -------
    ------
    }
}
```

the above function creates a label and on click , it does some operation. I can able to test the creation of label, but not the click event. All examples were given for angular, not for pure typescript. Let me know any ideas to proceed further.

Version:
ts: 2.8